# How to interpret this timing diagram?

Tags: digital-logic, signal

I am very confused on how to interpret this timing diagram?

[image]

Comment: will fix question

Comment: It is a bad timing diagram. Good timing diagram would show an arrow indicating which edge causes the change of state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the colors of the wires in the schematic are supposed to indicate the logic level of the signals. Specifically, the schematic is showing the state of the circuit at the point indicated by the vertical yellow line in the timing diagram, just after the falling edge of S. Q and E are high so they are red; S, R, and Q-bar are low so they are blue.

Having said that, using red and blue as colors of signals in the **timing diagram** seems like a very poor choice to me. I suggest you ignore the colors of the signals in the timing diagram; they don't seem to have any significance.

Answer (score 0):

Timing diagrams represent timing to reach valid logic states. The timing is usually the same to reach all states.

Truth tables represent all possible states assuming all timing is valid.

Answer (score 0):

The color in the schematic will represent whether the signal is high or low at that particular point.  So blue would be '0' (low) and red would be '1' (high).

There is however no correlation between the colors in the **timing diagram** and the **schematic**.  I think this may be confusing to someone that is looking at first without any background on what the colors mean.